# Workspace carrying over into other workspaces

Tags: gnome, workspaces

I have a problem where if I am in workspace 2 and go to workspace 1, apps in workspace 2 carry over to workspace 1.

I tried typing this command:

gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only false
settings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock isolate-workspaces false
But this gave an error.

I am using:

Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS 64 bit
Gnome 3.36.8

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

For dash-to-dock: `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock isolate-workspaces true`

For app-switcher: `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only true`

Changes take place immediately...You don't need to reboot